# How to get image in the cshtml which is inside the bin folder

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I have the image inside the folder, which is in the project root directory, as shown in the image below:

[image]

In the database the image path is stored as:

```
/image/aebebcf2-c253-4b84-926e-a1a0b079927f.webp
```

To display the image in the ui I have done as:

```
 var viewModel = new BlogPostEditViewModel
 {
    ImageURL = Url.Content("~/uploads/blogs/" + _fileService.BlogImageDirectory(blogPost.Image)),
 };
```

**BlogImageDirectory**

```
public string BlogImageDirectory(string imagePath)
{
    return imagePath.TrimStart('/'); // 
}
```

In the view, I am displaying the image as:

```
<img src="@Url.Content(Model.ImageURL)" class="img-fluid">
```

And I have the image copied to the bin folder as well:

[image]

However, in the UI I am getting the error the file not found:

```
The URL is generated as:

https://localhost:7071/uploads/blogs/image/aebebcf2-c253-4b84-926e-a1a0b079927f.webp
```

and the generated html is:

```
<div class="form-group mb-3">
    <div id="imagePreview">
        <img src="/uploads/blogs/image/aebebcf2-c253-4b84-926e-a1a0b079927f.webp" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
</div>
```

There wouldn't be any issue if I have stored the file inside the wwwroot folder, but i am stuck when the folder is inside the project root directory.

How can I access the image inside the other folder?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to better use the standard approach of serving static files from web root folder (by default it is the `webroot` folder, but it can be changed). In the Program.cs add the `UseStaticFiles` call:

```cs
// ...
var app = builder.Build();
// ...
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseAuthorization();
// ...
```

And add folders `uploads/blogs/image/` to `webroot` folder and place your images there.

Read more:

- [Static files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: I had already used, `app.UseStaticFiles();` in my code, I think i will update the folder structure like as you suggested.